# Django - Performance between images as fields vs images as ForeignKey model

Tags: django

I have a model called `Listing`.  Users can upload up to 20 photos for each Listing.

My question is: Performance-wise, is it better to create 20 fields for `Listing`, and leave them blank if the user doesn't fill them, or create a `ListingPhoto` foreignkey and create 1 ListingPhoto for each uploaded image?

---

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    img_1 = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    img_2 = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    ...
    img_20 = models.ImageField(blank=True)
```

OR

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    ...

class ListingPhoto(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = = models.ImageField()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, using 20 image field will be faster for sure as there is no joins required when you are retrieving these images. But this is not very flexible. You can consider using `ArrayField` or `JSONField` to be both flexible and require no joins.

Comment: I came across [this post](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25756), which says the FileField (and ImageField) doesn't work with ArrayField

Comment: You would handle the upload / delete in your code, and store the url to the file as string in the array.